# Is there a meaningful way to use context managers inside generators?

Tags: python, generator, contextmanager

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def context():
    print "entering"
    yield
    print "exiting"

def test():
    with context():
        for x in range(10):
            yield x

for x in test():
    if x == 5:
        break  # or raise
```

output:

```
entering
```

Is there a way to make python automatically invoke the `__exit__` method of context() when the `for`-loop is interrupted? Or some other way of achieving the same aim? What I know about generators and context managers makes me suspect it's not possible, but this makes context managers rather useless inside generators, doesn't it? It seems to me, a `yield` statement inside a `with` block should raise a red flag, **context manager `__exit__` may not run**.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well, you could wrap the yield in context() function with a try/finally clause:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def context():
    print "entering"
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        print "exiting"

def test():
    with context():
        for x in range(10):
            yield x

for x in test():
    if x == 5:
        break  # or raise
```

output:

```
entering
exiting
```

**Edit:** If you try a: **help(contextmanager)**, it will show it's "typical" useage example where they wrap the yield with a try/finally clause.

Comment: That's exactly what you're supposed to do: After the loop `test()` gets deleted, which raises `GeneratorExit()` at the `yield x`. That in turn breaks out of the `with: for:` block. Then the contextmanager catches the `GeneratorExit()` again and raises it at the yield in `context` - and that's where you have to catch it, else the `context` ends right there (it's a generator too after all, so this exception ends it silently) without doing the cleanup. The docs state that: "Thus, you can use a try...except...finally statement to trap the error (if any), or ensure that some cleanup takes place"